# Slot Machine displays zeros as results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple slot machine using this [plugin](https://github.com/josex2r/jQuery-SlotMachine).

I have an input field, that determines how many times the slot machine will shuffle, and a button that displays the modal then automatically runs the slot machine.

On the first try, it works fine, but when I close the modal, and run again. all the results are zeros.

Hope you help me.

Thanks.

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/xJKbKx)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myBtn').click(function(){
    let rolls = $("#rolls").val();
    console.log(rolls);    
    $('#myModal').show();
    var machine1 = $('#machine1').slotMachine();
    var machine2 = $('#machine2').slotMachine();
    var machine3 = $('#machine3').slotMachine();
    var machine4 = $('#machine4').slotMachine();
    var machine5 = $('#machine5').slotMachine();

    var arrResult = [];
  
    setTimeout(function(){
      machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
      machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
      machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
      machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
      machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
    }, 500);

    function onComplete(active){
      arrResult.push(this.active);
      if (arrResult.length === 5) {
        var output = arrResult.join('');
        console.log(output);
        rolls--;
        arrResult = [];
    
        $('table > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ output +'</td></tr>');
    
        if(rolls > 0){
          setTimeout(function(){ 
            machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
            machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
            machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
            machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
            machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
          }, 1500);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.modal').hide();
    $('table tbody tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.machine{
    height: 20px;
    max-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 200px; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://josex2r.github.io/jQuery-SlotMachine/dist/jquery.slotmachine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://josex2r.github.io/jQuery-SlotMachine/dist/slotmachine.js"></script><script src="http://josex2r.github.io/jQuery-SlotMachine/dist/jquery.slotmachine.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<input type="number" id="rolls">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content --> 
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <div id="machine1" class="machine">
       <div>0</div>
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       <div>4</div>
       <div>5</div>
       <div>6</div>
       <div>7</div>
       <div>8</div>
       <div>9</div>
     </div>
    <div id="machine2" class="machine">
      <div>0</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="machine3" class="machine">
      <div>0</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="machine4" class="machine">
      <div>0</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="machine5" class="machine">
      <div>0</div>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <table>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to close the modal sir then run again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the machines outside the button click seems to solve it for me,
it appears that the plugin is getting confused when you recreate the instances for each click.

If you want to do something more elegant you might want to look up the .destroy() method on the documentation.

not the prettiest solution but:

```
var machine1 = $('#machine1').slotMachine();
var machine2 = $('#machine2').slotMachine();
var machine3 = $('#machine3').slotMachine();
var machine4 = $('#machine4').slotMachine();
var machine5 = $('#machine5').slotMachine();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myBtn').click(function(){
    let rolls = $("#rolls").val();
    console.log(rolls);    
    $('#myModal').show();

    var arrResult = [];

    setTimeout(function(){
      machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
      machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
      machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
      machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
      machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
    }, 500);

    function onComplete(active){
      arrResult.push(this.active);
      if (arrResult.length === 5) {
        var output = arrResult.join('');
        console.log(output);
        rolls--;
        arrResult = [];

        $('table > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ output +'</td></tr>');

        if(rolls > 0){
          setTimeout(function(){ 
            machine1.shuffle(10, onComplete);
            machine2.shuffle(15, onComplete);
            machine3.shuffle(20, onComplete);
            machine4.shuffle(25, onComplete);
            machine5.shuffle(30, onComplete);
          }, 1500);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  $('.close').click(function(){
    $('.modal').hide();
    $('table tbody tr').remove();
  });
});
```

You can solve the off-by-one issue by putting the div with the 0 on the end of each list, here is a bin of the script running

http://jsbin.com/hehuxupapa/1/edit?html,js,output

PS: pretty cool plugin

Comment: let me try it sir

Comment: doesnt work sir, the default value should be all zeros, also the animation doesnt work. but the result is ok.

Comment: @Mark I don't get the issue about the animation, but you can solve the problem with the starting value by simply putting the 0 in the end of the list, I'll link a bin on the answer

Comment: ok sir. the transition of numbers while shuffling doesn't work if you put the declaration outside the click event, also the initial value change from 00000 to 99999.

Comment: @Mark check the link on my edit - it has the solution to get the starting value back to 00000 , from my side the animation looks ok, maybe you might want to add the information about your browser so we can help you further.

Comment: no problem, What with the sir tho? I'm feeling british right now, hehehe... if this for you works please upvote, I need reassurance today